# Should "clickable" areas in iOS be buttons?

Tags: ios

Should "clickable" areas in iOS be buttons or is it ok to just use a generic UIView, UIImage and so on?

Say i have a block of text with an icon, borders, shadows and so on. It looks like a bilboard. What would be the best way to implement that? Using a custom UIButton and just add subviews to it or creating just a generic UIView?

Any thoughts appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add `UIGestureRecognizer`s to your `UIView` and handle them. You can find the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and a tutorial [here](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/01/gesture-recognition-on-ios-with-attention-to-detail/).

Comment: fantastic.  capture the raw flow of events!  dig it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably for a view containing multiple subviews, you want to use a `UIView` subclass. While a `UIButton` would be OK for adding views, state changes, enabling/disabling may do wonky things to the view as a whole (including the subviews). Using your own `UIView` subclass will ensure that what gets displayed doesn't get toyed around with by any state changes, giving you complete control. You can override

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

to intercept touches on your custom view. If you're going to do this, remember that the userInteractionEnabled field MUST be set to true.

An additional note: you mentioned shadows as one of the elements in your question. If you're using `CALayer` to do this, **definitely** avoid using UIButton, as it's set of layers to handle different states is quite complex.

Answer (score -1):

If the target area is big enough, you could place a transparent UIButton (switch the button type to custom, but don't supply an image) over the top of the clickable view to intercept the taps.